# Can custom Django filters access request.user?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Is it possible to access the current `User` (i.e. `user` in the template context) from a custom template filter?

Obviously I can pass the user in as an argument, but if it's possible to just grab the current user, that would be more convenient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django filters aren't given any special access to the context from which they are called, they're just plain old functions.

You'll need to pass in anything you want to use within the function.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Sad. I suppose I could always do something with middleware or template context processors to set a thread local, but... yuck.

Comment: Though first it feels PITA, replacing a filter with a template tag is quite easy with `@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)`

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28098279/201945

But, in short, you CAN access the `context` from within a custom filter by extracting it from the call stack when, and only when, the filter is called during render.

This is, admittedly, a haphazard solution.  Caveat emptor.