# passing request in django template tag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I tried to access the `request` in my custom template tag function. But it is not working.

views.py

```
def candidate(request):
   .......
   .......
   return render(request, template, context)
```

templatetags

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def make_url(context, doc_url):
    request = context["request"]
    protocol = "https://" if request.is_secure() else "http://"
    host = request.get_host()
    new_url = "%s%s%s" %(protocol, host, doc_url)
    return new_url
```

template.html

```
<iframe src="{{  candidate.resume_file.url | make_url }}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: What's not working?  Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: are you trying to write a custom template tag or custom filter ?

Comment: thanks for your comments. sorry i got the problem. changed register.filter to register.simple_tag. i replaced this {{ candidate.resume_file.url | make_url }} with {% make_url candidate.resume_file.url %}  in html

Comment: you should not change "filter" to "simple_tag" in your question....this make others, like me..., feel confuse.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django filters aren't given any special access to the context from which they are called, they're just plain old functions.

You'll need to pass in anything you want to use within the function.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

source : [Can custom Django filters access request.user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683466/can-custom-django-filters-access-request-user)